# Rails root_path in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, codemirror

How can I get my hands on the project's `root_path` in my **application.js** file?

I need it for a js plugin (**codemirror**) that needs to load other JS files. It's all fine and dandy if I say "/javascripts/needed_file.js", but what if I deploy my project to "/custom".

The code needs to do its magic all over the project and I would like it to be UJS, so it needs to be in a static javascript file.

Any solutions/simple hacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no beautiful solution. I'd try one of these approaches:

- Inspect `window.location.pathname`. Determine from this whether running from root or from a prefix url.
- Add something like `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var ROOT_PATH = '<%= Rails.root_path %>';</script>` somewhere to the top of your layout file.
- Use this quite hackish function (I suspect that it might break with some of the HTML5 script attributes):

  ```
  function urlOfCurrentFile() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    return scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
  }
  ```

Comment: i actually have a link to the homepage in my site... so it was as easy as $('#header a').attr('href'). Stil quite hackish but it works so i can't complain.. thank you

Comment: The `<script>` method is the best one I think (because you can change you banner one day, change the link, change the selector, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

I have this in my header file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var BASE_URL = '<%= root_url %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way I find is to leverage the power of JS to do so, like:

```
window.location.origin # http://localhost:3000/
```

It's gonna give you the complete hostname, with `http://`, and the port number. Like in case of running Rails server locally, it will give you: `http://localhost:3000`

```
window.location.hostname # localhost
```

It's just gonna give you the name of host, and nothing about port or HTTP. Incase of Rails server running locally, it will give you: `localhost`.